# So close I can taste it

Tags: word

I'm looking for something both *special* and kind of arbitrary.

If you agree, it follows *O* and precedes *La*.

Perhaps soon it will find me here.

But by then I'll have ten.

Comment: Brent - Congratulations on the 10K - if questions were 10 and answers 5, you'd have a score and I'd have five.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for

> K

I'm looking for something both special and kind of arbitrary.

> [*Special K*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_K). K as a letter on its own may be seen as arbitrary.

If you agree, it follows O and precedes La.

> *OK So* - signifies agreement. *So* precedes *La* in musical solfège.

Perhaps soon it will find me here.

> Your are almost at 10,000 rep points which will be written as 10K

But by then I'll have ten.

> 10,000 = 10K

Sidenote

> Congratulations!

Comment: Correct, and arbitrary *woo!*

Comment: Wow that was farfetched

Comment: Following O and preceding La could also be Oklahoma - also a stretch, but doesn't require an extra word to make sense